# where shall i place admin.py in a project of multiple apps to register model of a particular app

Tags: python-2.7, django-admin

structure of my django project is as follows:

```
project
  - all_apps
     - app1
          -templates
          -forms.py, models.py,urls.py,views.py
  - project_wide_configs
      - settings.py, urls.py, views.py
```

project_wide_configs directory contains all settings. 
i have to register models of app1, for this i placed admin.py in that folder, and registered the model, but it wasnt shown in the admin.

urls.py of project_wide_configs contains admin urls.

Comment: Please post out the INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py.

Comment: @Dinever, how INSTALLED_APPS is related to this? i've added it to installed_apps and admin.py in app1, and its models are showing in the admin.